# Find whether event's timestamp is within a time interval

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, data.table

I have one data.frame with **events** and their arrival timestamps (microsecond precision). In the second dataframe I have the **states** with start and end times (= validity interval).

Below I wrote for loop routine which does the job but **is really slow**.
I think that a combination of data.table, map/apply, parallelization (I have 12 cores available) could substantially reduce the processing time.

Could you please help to optimize my code?

Thanks!

```
options(digits.secs = 6)

start <- strptime("2019-10-16 08:00:00.789543 CET", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
start <- format(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

end <- strptime("2019-10-16 08:10:00.471123 CET", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
end <- format(end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")


#### events
event_timestamps <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(start), 
                    as.POSIXct(end), units = "seconds", by = .1)
events <- sprintf("event%s",seq(1:length(event_timestamps)))


events_df <- data.frame(event_timestamps, events, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#### states
states <- sprintf("state%s",seq(1:4))

state_start <- c("2019-10-16 07:00:00.000000 CEST",
                 "2019-10-16 08:03:00.765233 CEST",
                 "2019-10-16 08:05:03.765432 CEST",
                 "2019-10-16 08:05:03.765434")


state_end <- c("2019-10-16 08:03:00.765232 CEST",
               "2019-10-16 08:05:03.765431 CEST",
               "2019-10-16 08:05:03.765433 CEST",
               "2019-10-16 08:12:03.471122 CEST")

states_df <- data.frame(states, state_start = as.POSIXct(state_start),
                        state_end = as.POSIXct(state_end), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#The state dataframe contains states with non-overlapping start and end timestamps.
#That means that one event can fall into exactly one state
# the goal is for every event to find the state it belongs to

#########################################################################

library(lubridate)

# empty data.frame
resulting_df <- data.frame(events = character(),
                           state = character(),
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 



# loop eventy by event
for(event in 1:nrow(events_df)) {
  # go with the event to the states data.frame
  for (state in 1:nrow(states_df)) {
    # define state's interval
    interv <- lubridate::interval(states_df$state_start[state], states_df$state_end[state], tzone = 'CET') 
    # check for every event if its timestamp is within the state interval
    if (events_df$event_timestamps[event] %within% interv){

      # then write the temp data.frame
      temp <- data.frame(events = events_df$events[event],
                         state = states_df$states[state],
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      # collect events with states
      resulting_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(resulting_df, temp)
      rm(temp)
      # one event can only be in one state at a time
      # after we found the state for the event, break the inner state loop
      # and move to the next event
      break
      next
    }


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rolling join in `data.table` for this. The idea here is that you set the key for each `data.table` to be either the event time or the starting time for the state. The join will then match each event to the most recent starting state time. And since you have non-overlapping states, this achieves what you want.

```r
## Your creation code above
#########################################################################

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(tictoc)
tic()
# empty data.frame
resulting_df <- data.frame(events = character(),
                           state = character(),
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 



# loop eventy by event
for(event in 1:nrow(events_df)) {
  # go with the event to the states data.frame
  for (state in 1:nrow(states_df)) {
    # define state's interval
    interv <- lubridate::interval(states_df$state_start[state], states_df$state_end[state], tzone = 'CET') 
    # check for every event if its timestamp is within the state interval
    if (events_df$event_timestamps[event] %within% interv){

      # then write the temp data.frame
      temp <- data.frame(events = events_df$events[event],
                         state = states_df$states[state],
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      # collect events with states
      resulting_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(resulting_df, temp)
      rm(temp)
      # one event can only be in one state at a time
      # after we found the state for the event, break the inner state loop
      # and move to the next event
      break
      next
    }


  }

}
toc()
#> 9.61 sec elapsed

library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday,
#>     week, yday, year
events_dt <- data.table(events_df)
states_dt <- data.table(states_df)
setkey(states_dt, state_start)
setkey(events_dt, event_timestamps)
tic()
resulting_dt <- states_dt[events_dt, roll = T][,.(events, states)]
toc()
#> 0 sec elapsed
all(data.table(resulting_df) == resulting_dt)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `foverlaps` in the `data.table` package as follows (It's very fast!):

```
setDT(states_df, key = c("state_start", "state_end"))
cols <- c("state_start", "state_end")
setDT(events_df)[, (cols) := event_timestamps]

foverlaps(events_df, states_df)[, paste0("i.", cols) := NULL]
```

To understand how the function `foverlaps` works, it's better to read its documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.4/topics/foverlaps)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sqldf package. Not sure how efficient it is on your full dataset, but this should work:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT events_df.events, states_df.states 
       FROM events_df INNER JOIN states_df 
       ON events_df.event_timestamps BETWEEN states_df.state_start AND states_df.state_end')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack something together using the `intervals` package. Here is my quick and messy attempt:

```
int_mat = intervals::Intervals(cbind(as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", state_start)), 
                                     as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", state_end))))
point_mat = intervals::Intervals(cbind(as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", event_timestamps)), 
                                       as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", event_timestamps))))
ls = intervals::interval_included(int_mat, point_mat)
# ls[[n]] are indices of points that belong to the n-th interval
```

Note that `Intervals()` only accepts numeric matrices, so first I convert the timestamps to integers. All timestamps need to be in exactly the same format and include leading/trailing zeros (or just use different way to convert them to integers than I did).

Answer (score 0):

Some timings for reference using functions from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.4

s <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2019-10-01 00:00:00.000000 CET", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
e <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2019-10-10 23:59:59.999999 CET", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))

#8,640,000 rows
events <- data.table(TIME=seq.POSIXt(s, e, units="seconds", by=.1))[, EVENT := .I]

#863,999 rows
h <- seq.POSIXt(s, e, units="hour", by=1)
states <- data.table(STATE=seq_len(length(h)-1L), START=h[-length(h)], END=h[-1L],
    key=c("START","END"))

events_foverlap <- copy(events)[, c("START", "END") := TIME]
states_foverlap <- copy(states)
setkey(events, TIME)

dt_foverlap <- function() {
    ans <- foverlaps(events_foverlap, states_foverlap, type="any", mult="first")
    ans[, .N]
}

dt_nonequi <- function() {
    ans <- states[events, on=.(START<=TIME, END>=TIME), mult="first"]
    ans[,.N]
}

dt_roll <- function() {
    ans <- states[events, roll=TRUE]   
    ans[,.N]
}

bench::mark(dt_foverlap(), dt_nonequi(), dt_roll())
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory             time     gc              
  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>             <list>   <list>          
1 dt_foverlap()    2.99s    2.99s     0.335    1.24GB    1.00      1     3      2.99s <int [1]> <df[,3] [122 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 dt_nonequi()     3.78s    3.78s     0.265  372.55MB    0.265     1     1      3.78s <int [1]> <df[,3] [43 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 dt_roll()        1.09s    1.09s     0.918  329.69MB    0.918     1     1      1.09s <int [1]> <df[,3] [33 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```